# Efficient way to apply function with multiple operations on dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
            X[m]      Y[m]      Z[m]  ...      beta  newx  newy
0       1.439485  0.087100  0.029771  ...  0.063807  1439    87
1       1.439485  0.089729  0.029121  ...  0.065871  1439    89
2       1.439485  0.091992  0.030059  ...  0.067653  1439    91
3       1.439485  0.082073  0.030721  ...  0.059883  1439    82
4       1.439485  0.084095  0.028952  ...  0.061458  1439    84
5       1.439485  0.085937  0.028019  ...  0.062897  1439    85
```

There are hundreds of thousands of such lines, while I have multiple dataframes like this. X and Y are coordinates on plane (Z is not important) that is moved 45 degrees by the middle to the right. I need to put all points back to the original place, -45 degrees from its location. I have variables `newx` and `newy` that represent coordinates before changing, I want to edit these two columns to have values of new coordinates. As I know coordinates of middle point, the point itself, the angle of middle-to-point (alpha) and angle middle-to-fixedpoint (beta), I can use [approach presented in mathematics SO](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990698/intersection-of-two-lines-each-defined-by-a-point-and-an-angle). I have transformed the code to python like this:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i].alpha == math.pi/2 or df.iloc[i].alpha == 3*math.pi/2:
        df.newx[i] = mid
        df.newy[i] = int(math.tan(df.iloc[i].beta*(df.iloc[i].x-mid)+mid))
    elif df.iloc[i].beta == math.pi/2 or df.iloc[i].beta == 3*math.pi/2:
        #df.newx[i] = df.iloc[i].x -- this is already set
        df.newy[i] = int(math.tan(df.iloc[i].alpha*(mid-df.iloc[i].x)+mid))
    else:
        m0 = math.tan(df.iloc[i].alpha)
        m1 = math.tan(df.iloc[i].beta)
        x = ((m0 * df.iloc[i].x - m1 * mid) - (df.iloc[i].y - mid)) / (m0 - m1)
        df.newx[i] = int(x)
        df.newy[i] = int(m0 * (x - df.iloc[i].x) + df.iloc[i].y)
```

Although this does what I need and moves the point to the correct position, the time complexity is enormous and I have too much files to proceed it like this. I know that there are way faster methods, such as serialization, apply and list comprehension. I however can't figure out how to use it with this function.

Here are first 10 lines as dictionary:

```
{'X[m]': {0: 1.439484727008419, 1: 1.439484727008419, 2: 1.439484727008419, 3: 1.439484727008419, 4: 1.439484727008419, 5: 1.439484727008419, 6: 1.439484727008419, 7: 1.439484727008419, 8: 1.439484727008419, 9: 1.439484727008419}, 'Y[m]': {0: 0.08709958190841899, 1: 0.08972904270841897, 2: 0.091991981408419, 3: 0.08207325440841898, 4: 0.08409548540841899, 5: 0.08593746080841899, 6: 0.09416210370841899, 7: 0.08874029660841898, 8: 0.09168940400841899, 9: 0.09434491760841898}, 'Z[m]': {0: 0.029770726299999998, 1: 0.0291213803, 2: 0.030058834700000002, 3: 0.0307212565, 4: 0.028951926200000002, 5: 0.0280194897, 6: 0.030717188500000003, 7: 0.026446931099999998, 8: 0.0269318204, 9: 0.0273838975}, 'Velocity[ms^-1]': {0: ['-1.67570162e+00', '-2.59946979e-15', '-2.54510192e-15'], 1: ['-1.63915336e+00', '-2.54277343e-15', '-2.48959140e-15'], 2: ['-1.69191790e+00', '-2.62462561e-15', '-2.56973173e-15'], 3: ['-1.72920227e+00', '-2.68246377e-15', '-2.62636012e-15'], 4: ['-1.62961555e+00', '-2.52797767e-15', '-2.47510523e-15'], 5: ['-1.57713342e+00', '-2.44656340e-15', '-2.39539372e-15'], 6: ['-1.72897375e+00', '-2.68210929e-15', '-2.62601305e-15'], 7: ['-1.48862195e+00', '-2.30925809e-15', '-2.26096006e-15'], 8: ['-1.51591396e+00', '-2.35159534e-15', '-2.30241195e-15'], 9: ['-1.54135919e+00', '-2.39106792e-15', '-2.34105888e-15']}, 'L': {0: 0.9582306809661671, 1: 0.9564957485824027, 2: 0.9550059224371557, 3: 0.9615583774318917, 4: 0.9602177760259737, 5: 0.9589987519260235, 6: 0.9535800607266656, 7: 0.9571476500665267, 8: 0.9552049510914844, 9: 0.953460072490227}, 'x': {0: 1439, 1: 1439, 2: 1439, 3: 1439, 4: 1439, 5: 1439, 6: 1439, 7: 1439, 8: 1439, 9: 1439}, 'y': {0: 87, 1: 89, 2: 91, 3: 82, 4: 84, 5: 85, 6: 94, 7: 88, 8: 91, 9: 94}, 'alpha': {0: -0.7215912027987663, 1: -0.719527331916007, 2: -0.7177451479100487, 3: -0.7255156166536015, 4: -0.7239399868865558, 5: -0.7225009735356016, 6: -0.7160308360594005, 7: -0.7203042790640757, 8: -0.7179837655204843, 9: -0.7158861861473951}, 'beta': {0: 0.06380696059868196, 1: 0.06587083148144124, 2: 0.06765301548739955, 3: 0.05988254674384674, 4: 0.06145817651089247, 5: 0.06289718986184667, 6: 0.06936732733804774, 7: 0.0650938843333726, 8: 0.06741439787696402, 9: 0.0695119772500532}, 'newx': {0: 1439, 1: 1439, 2: 1439, 3: 1439, 4: 1439, 5: 1439, 6: 1439, 7: 1439, 8: 1439, 9: 1439}, 'newy': {0: 87, 1: 89, 2: 91, 3: 82, 4: 84, 5: 85, 6: 94, 7: 88, 8: 91, 9: 94}}
```

Comment: Checking for equality against a `float` smells...

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp I will deal with that problem later, I am aware that it may not end up as I wish but now I have to make it run in reasonable time

Comment: can you provide a small proof-of-concept input `df` and expected output to test against, perhaps `df.head(10).to_dict()`?

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp I have edited the question.

Comment: Can you explain more thoroughly the problem? I do not understand 'X and Y are coordinates on plane that is moved 45 degrees by the middle to the right.". What is "middle"? What does mean moving a plane? (I would understand "rotate", "translate" or "scale"). Can you state the question using a transformation matrix?

Comment: I agree with @hpchavaz, your description is very confusing. Please share a small diagram, showing the initial and final position of the point, and identifying all the relevant variables (positions and angles). And clarify the correspondence of those variables with the columns of your DataFrame.

Comment: @hpchavaz I believe the real meaning of what I need to achieve is not important here as I already have a code, just need to make it run faster, but yes, the data is square-like, thus can be represented as a NxN matrix. The middle is meant to be point of rotation in the middle, so N/2. Thus in fact it is a coordinate system, and all points are rotated 45 degrees by the axis of rotation starting in middle point, in code named mid. I need to get them back. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: @Ruli what is the `type/dtype` of `mid`? Does `mid` have an x-coordinate and a y-coordinate?

Comment: @Ruli the context is often useful to understand some points. In the present cas the context could have explained what `mid` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect how we're using `mid` as from your code may be causing you problems. Is `mid` a numeric? Are the x- and y-coordinates of your middle point the same value?

---

@OP, please confirm your variable names as compared to your linked source are as I have translated them:

| linked name | your name |
| --- | --- |
| `a0` | `beta` |
| `a1` | `alpha` |
| `(x0, y0)` | `(df.x, df.y)` |
| `(x1, y1)` | `(mid, mid)` |

---

**Update** this answer shares some ideas with [@mitoRibo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6580543/mitoribo)'s answer, but I re-translated from OP's linked source and suspect OP made some transcription error. Noted in comments. Both of us used a strategy of "selectively calculate `newx/newy` using masking, where the masks are equivalent to the `if/elif/else` conditions provided".

```py
#setup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

df = pd.DataFrame({'X[m]': {0: 1.439484727008419, 1: 1.439484727008419, 2: 1.439484727008419, 3: 1.439484727008419, 4: 1.439484727008419, 5: 1.439484727008419, 6: 1.439484727008419, 7: 1.439484727008419, 8: 1.439484727008419, 9: 1.439484727008419}, 'Y[m]': {0: 0.08709958190841899, 1: 0.08972904270841897, 2: 0.091991981408419, 3: 0.08207325440841898, 4: 0.08409548540841899, 5: 0.08593746080841899, 6: 0.09416210370841899, 7: 0.08874029660841898, 8: 0.09168940400841899, 9: 0.09434491760841898}, 'Z[m]': {0: 0.029770726299999998, 1: 0.0291213803, 2: 0.030058834700000002, 3: 0.0307212565, 4: 0.028951926200000002, 5: 0.0280194897, 6: 0.030717188500000003, 7: 0.026446931099999998, 8: 0.0269318204, 9: 0.0273838975}, 'Velocity[ms^-1]': {0: ['-1.67570162e+00', '-2.59946979e-15', '-2.54510192e-15'], 1: ['-1.63915336e+00', '-2.54277343e-15', '-2.48959140e-15'], 2: ['-1.69191790e+00', '-2.62462561e-15', '-2.56973173e-15'], 3: ['-1.72920227e+00', '-2.68246377e-15', '-2.62636012e-15'], 4: ['-1.62961555e+00', '-2.52797767e-15', '-2.47510523e-15'], 5: ['-1.57713342e+00', '-2.44656340e-15', '-2.39539372e-15'], 6: ['-1.72897375e+00', '-2.68210929e-15', '-2.62601305e-15'], 7: ['-1.48862195e+00', '-2.30925809e-15', '-2.26096006e-15'], 8: ['-1.51591396e+00', '-2.35159534e-15', '-2.30241195e-15'], 9: ['-1.54135919e+00', '-2.39106792e-15', '-2.34105888e-15']}, 'L': {0: 0.9582306809661671, 1: 0.9564957485824027, 2: 0.9550059224371557, 3: 0.9615583774318917, 4: 0.9602177760259737, 5: 0.9589987519260235, 6: 0.9535800607266656, 7: 0.9571476500665267, 8: 0.9552049510914844, 9: 0.953460072490227}, 'x': {0: 1439, 1: 1439, 2: 1439, 3: 1439, 4: 1439, 5: 1439, 6: 1439, 7: 1439, 8: 1439, 9: 1439}, 'y': {0: 87, 1: 89, 2: 91, 3: 82, 4: 84, 5: 85, 6: 94, 7: 88, 8: 91, 9: 94}, 'alpha': {0: -0.7215912027987663, 1: -0.719527331916007, 2: -0.7177451479100487, 3: -0.7255156166536015, 4: -0.7239399868865558, 5: -0.7225009735356016, 6: -0.7160308360594005, 7: -0.7203042790640757, 8: -0.7179837655204843, 9: -0.7158861861473951}, 'beta': {0: 0.06380696059868196, 1: 0.06587083148144124, 2: 0.06765301548739955, 3: 0.05988254674384674, 4: 0.06145817651089247, 5: 0.06289718986184667, 6: 0.06936732733804774, 7: 0.0650938843333726, 8: 0.06741439787696402, 9: 0.0695119772500532}})

# make the new columns
df['newx'] = np.nan
df['newy'] = np.nan
# if any of the values are np.nan when we're done, something went wrong

# Do the float `between` comparison but cleverly
EPSILON = 1e-6
# windows = ((pi/2 ± EPSILON), (3pi/2 ± EPSILON))
windows = tuple(tuple(d*math.pi/2 + s*EPSILON for s in (1, -1)) for d in (1, 3))
# challenge: make this more DRY (don't repeat yourself)
alpha_cond = sum([df.alpha.between(*w) for w in windows]).astype(bool)
beta_cond  = sum([ df.beta.between(*w) for w in windows]).astype(bool)\
                 & ~alpha_cond
neither = (~alpha_cond & ~beta_cond)

# Handle `alpha near pi/2 or 3pi/2`:
c1 = df.loc[alpha_cond]
df.loc[alpha_cond,'newx'] = mid
                                         # changed `tan` parenthesis
                                         # |    changed `df.x - mid` to `mid - df.x`
                                         # |    |             changed to `df.y` from `mid`
df.loc[alpha_cond,'newy'] = (np.tan(c1.beta) * (mid - c1.x) + c1.y).astype(int)

# Handle `beta near pi/2 or 3pi/2`:
c2 = df.loc[beta_cond]
df loc[beta_cond,'newx'] = c2.x
                                         # changed `tan` parenthesis
                                         # |    changed `mid - df.x` to `df.x - mid`
df.loc[beta_cond,'newy'] = (np.tan(c2.alpha) * (c2.x - mid) + mid).astype(int)

# Handle the remainder:
c3 = df.loc[neither]
m0 = np.tan(c3.alpha)
m1 = np.tan(c3.beta)
t = ((m0 * c3.x - m1 * mid) - (c3.y - mid)) / (m0 - m1)

df.loc[neither,'newx'] = t.astype(int)
df.loc[neither,'newy'] = (m0 * (t - c3.x) + c3.y).astype(int)
```

Comment: looks great, and I bet its really fast. one suggestion is that `df.beta.between(dn_min, dn_max)` saves some typing

Comment: @Ruli I checked source against your linked SO answer and made some changes; noted in comments. Short version: I think you may have made some transcription errors. Would you confirm my translation table?

Comment: alpha and beta are reverse, a0 is alpha, I am going to work on it shortly and will see where I have made a mistake :)

Comment: the code works now, I had some logical errors as well in code irrelevant to this, which caused incorrect angles to be count. As I fixed those your code works (keeping in mind you have swapped alpha and beta) and is significantly faster than mine which was aim of question.

Answer (score 3):

Same approach as @Joshua Voskamp, but I still wanted to share

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

df = pd.DataFrame({'X[m]': {0: 1.439484727008419, 1: 1.439484727008419, 2: 1.439484727008419, 3: 1.439484727008419, 4: 1.439484727008419, 5: 1.439484727008419, 6: 1.439484727008419, 7: 1.439484727008419, 8: 1.439484727008419, 9: 1.439484727008419}, 'Y[m]': {0: 0.08709958190841899, 1: 0.08972904270841897, 2: 0.091991981408419, 3: 0.08207325440841898, 4: 0.08409548540841899, 5: 0.08593746080841899, 6: 0.09416210370841899, 7: 0.08874029660841898, 8: 0.09168940400841899, 9: 0.09434491760841898}, 'Z[m]': {0: 0.029770726299999998, 1: 0.0291213803, 2: 0.030058834700000002, 3: 0.0307212565, 4: 0.028951926200000002, 5: 0.0280194897, 6: 0.030717188500000003, 7: 0.026446931099999998, 8: 0.0269318204, 9: 0.0273838975}, 'Velocity[ms^-1]': {0: ['-1.67570162e+00', '-2.59946979e-15', '-2.54510192e-15'], 1: ['-1.63915336e+00', '-2.54277343e-15', '-2.48959140e-15'], 2: ['-1.69191790e+00', '-2.62462561e-15', '-2.56973173e-15'], 3: ['-1.72920227e+00', '-2.68246377e-15', '-2.62636012e-15'], 4: ['-1.62961555e+00', '-2.52797767e-15', '-2.47510523e-15'], 5: ['-1.57713342e+00', '-2.44656340e-15', '-2.39539372e-15'], 6: ['-1.72897375e+00', '-2.68210929e-15', '-2.62601305e-15'], 7: ['-1.48862195e+00', '-2.30925809e-15', '-2.26096006e-15'], 8: ['-1.51591396e+00', '-2.35159534e-15', '-2.30241195e-15'], 9: ['-1.54135919e+00', '-2.39106792e-15', '-2.34105888e-15']}, 'L': {0: 0.9582306809661671, 1: 0.9564957485824027, 2: 0.9550059224371557, 3: 0.9615583774318917, 4: 0.9602177760259737, 5: 0.9589987519260235, 6: 0.9535800607266656, 7: 0.9571476500665267, 8: 0.9552049510914844, 9: 0.953460072490227}, 'x': {0: 1439, 1: 1439, 2: 1439, 3: 1439, 4: 1439, 5: 1439, 6: 1439, 7: 1439, 8: 1439, 9: 1439}, 'y': {0: 87, 1: 89, 2: 91, 3: 82, 4: 84, 5: 85, 6: 94, 7: 88, 8: 91, 9: 94}, 'alpha': {0: -0.7215912027987663, 1: -0.719527331916007, 2: -0.7177451479100487, 3: -0.7255156166536015, 4: -0.7239399868865558, 5: -0.7225009735356016, 6: -0.7160308360594005, 7: -0.7203042790640757, 8: -0.7179837655204843, 9: -0.7158861861473951}, 'beta': {0: 0.06380696059868196, 1: 0.06587083148144124, 2: 0.06765301548739955, 3: 0.05988254674384674, 4: 0.06145817651089247, 5: 0.06289718986184667, 6: 0.06936732733804774, 7: 0.0650938843333726, 8: 0.06741439787696402, 9: 0.0695119772500532}, 'newx': {0: 1439, 1: 1439, 2: 1439, 3: 1439, 4: 1439, 5: 1439, 6: 1439, 7: 1439, 8: 1439, 9: 1439}, 'newy': {0: 87, 1: 89, 2: 91, 3: 82, 4: 84, 5: 85, 6: 94, 7: 88, 8: 91, 9: 94}})

mid = 0 #not sure what mid value should be

near_threshold = 0.001

alpha_near_half_pi = df.alpha.sub(math.pi/2).abs().le(near_threshold)
alpha_near_three_half_pi = df.alpha.sub(3*math.pi/2).abs().le(near_threshold)
beta_near_half_pi = df.beta.sub(math.pi/2).abs().le(near_threshold)
beta_near_three_half_pi = df.beta.sub(3*math.pi/2).abs().le(near_threshold)

cond1 = alpha_near_half_pi | alpha_near_three_half_pi
cond2 = beta_near_half_pi | beta_near_three_half_pi
cond2 = cond2 & (~cond1) #if cond1 is true, we don't want to do cond2
cond3 = ~(cond1 | cond2) #if neither cond1 nor cond2, then we are in cond3

#Process cond1 rows
c1 = df.loc[cond1]
df.loc[cond1,'newx'] = mid
df.loc[cond1,'newy'] = np.tan(c1.beta*(c1.x-mid)+mid)

#Process cond2 rows
c2 = df.loc[cond2]
df.loc[cond2,'newy'] = np.tan(c2.alpha*(mid-c2.x)+mid)

#Process cond3 rows
c3 = df.loc[cond3]
m0 = np.tan(c3.alpha)
m1 = np.tan(c3.beta)

#                       Is this a mistake? always 0?
#                                   |
#                             --------------
x = ((m0 * c3.x - m1 * mid) - (c3.y - c3.y)) / (m0 - m1)
df.loc[cond3,'newx'] = x.astype(int)
df.loc[cond3,'newy'] = (m0 * (x - c3.x) + c3.y).astype(int)

df
```

Comment: lol you found the same possible mistake I was unsure about

Comment: glad I'm not crazy haha

Comment: yes it should be -mid, checking out both solutions, thanks both, I would like to accept both answers but I can only one :)